# How to add OracleDriver to hadoop classpath while executing the job?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I'm using hadoop for processing a large amount of data from the database. I'm using oracle's jdbc driver to connect to Oracle DB and do the processing. But when i try to execute the hadoop job via `bin/hadoop` with the packaged JAR file, it's showing OracleDriver class not found. how do i fix this?

`$ bin/hadoop jar ~/hadoop1.jar name.hadoop.Hadoop1  ~/output`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getInputFormat(JobConf.java:575)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:1051)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1043)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$700(JobClient.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:959)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:912)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:912)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:886)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1323)
    at name.shahalpk.poc.hadoop.Hadoop1.main(Hadoop1.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.db.DBInputFormat.configure(DBInputFormat.java:271)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.db.DBConfiguration.getConnection(DBConfiguration.java:123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.db.DBInputFormat.configure(DBInputFormat.java:266)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: exception is occurring when you execute jar file , am I right?

Comment: You add the Oracle driver jar (ojdbc5.jar) to the classpath on all hadoop nodes.

Comment: @MohammodHossain exactly. see the updated question for more details.

Comment: Maybe check this: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#How_do_I_submit_extra_content_.28jars.2C_static_files.2C_etc.29_for_my_job_to_use_during_runtime.3F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add ojdbc5.jar into class path:

```
${JRE_HOME}\jre\lib\ext
```

Note:

```
${JRE_HOME} means JRE(Java Runtime Environment) Installed Directory; Like below
${JRE_HOME}=C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-libjars` generic option to achieve this more easily, and it handles distribution of your jar to the cluster nodes too:

```
$ bin/hadoop jar ~/hadoop1.jar name.hadoop.Hadoop1 -libjars ojdbc5.jar ~/output
```

This does assume that your main class (`name.hadoop.Hadoop1`) is using the ToolRunner.run() method to launch your job:

```
public class Hadoop1 extends Configured implements Tool {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    ToolRunner.run(new Hadoop1(), args);
  }

  public int run(String args[]) {
    JobConf job = new JobConf(getConf());

    // rest of your job init code...

    RunningJob rj = JobClient.runJob(job);
    rj.waitForCompletion();
    return rj.isSuccessful() ? 0 : 1;
  }
}
```

(Hand typed code, apologises for any typos or compile errors)